# jQuery: fadeOut 0 milliseconds or close to zero duration

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout, duration

I'm curious if I can set `fadeOut(10, function(){...});` - the duration of ten milliseconds. I've checked the jQuery official site but I can't find an answer Can the value be ANY non-negative number or some restrictions apply (you type 10(ms), but actually it is 100ms).
Also, can zero be used?

Comment: If you need 0 then use hide() instead of fadeOut()

Comment: Durations times are not limited.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, but in my case duration is a non-negative parameter. It's easier to pass 0, if it is allowed and it is really zero.

Comment: Yes, 0 can be used. Did you even try it? I'm sure you could have came to that conclusion on your own.

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sRhSw/1/

Comment: Agreed. *Just try it.* It's not like your computer is going to explode if it doesn't work. You're just wasting our time and yours with this question.

Comment: Sorry for my question. Tried it...Still had a question if this is correct. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [$.fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/). The jQuery FX Core uses this value to determine the number of frames per a second animations run. It defaults to 13 milliseconds, however it can be changed – although this can mess with the performance depending on the power of the browser and JS engine.

Setting a duration of less than this value would result in the animation duration being equivalent to using 0 or $.hide() directly.

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7bAt/1/) and notice how the console shows the completion of the $.fadeOut() in order that they appear in the script rather than there values as they are all effectively 0 since they are below the default $.fx.interval value.